# Internal Server Error and process graceful kill fail

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-fcgid

Internal Server Error is registered in browser, in the Apache error log file I can only see the following warn thrown in same time:

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: process XXXXX graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Are these two errors related each other?

Comment: Sounds like you have a long-running script or something as apache is killing the worker process. Check your scripts. What does your config look lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer on my question, the following error is also presented in the apache error log file:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

This comes from the fast cgi configuration, I increased the IOTimeout value in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf`

```
FcgidIOTimeout 45 to FcgidIOTimeout 300
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a related problem, with some suggestions on how to solve it:
[mod_fcgi in virtualmin:  graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/414088/mod-fcgi-in-virtualmin-graceful-kill-fail-sending-sigkill)